# Struggling with customer SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to pull the count of customers that fill the below parameters:

- have an interval of +365 days between their last order date and second to last order date
- ordered in 2020

I am struggling with two pieces. Honestly I'm just struggling with the whole thing.

1. How to pull second to last order date for a specific customers and then use that day for the interval calc
2. If I need to create a table of customers or pull in 2 separate queries

So far I have the interval calc correct, but it takes the max from the entire column rather than by customer.

```
select datediff(day, select max(ship_date) where ship_date < select max(ship_date) :: date, select max(ship_date) :: date)
```

I would need a count where customers have intervals > 365
and where (last_ship_date) or max(ship_date) >Jan 1 2020

Comment: Use `LAG()`, if you are using MySQL 8.x

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select customer_id
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by ship_date desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn <= 2
group by customer_id
having max(ship_date) >= '2020-01-01' 
   and max(ship_date) > min(ship_date) + interval 1 year
```

The idea is to filter on the two latest rows per customers. You can then compare the dates using aggregation.

Comment: This is similar to what I had, but need a way to choose the first order in 2020 vs just the max. Customers with multiple orders in 2020 are not coming through because the second to last order will just be also in 2020, and won't  be within the parameters we set.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for `lag()`:

```
select customer_id
from (select t.*, 
             lag(ship_date) over (partition by customer_id order by ship_date) as prev_ship_date
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by ship_date desc) as seqnum
       from t
      ) t
where seqnum = 1 and
      ship_date >= '2020-01-01' and
      prev_ship_date < ship_date - interval 1 year
```